# Mostrar todos los registros si se envía submit sin nada en los input

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando que al presionar el botón `submit` sin introducir nada en los `input` me muestre todos los datos que tengo en la DB, he intentado con consultas embebidas pero no he podido y quisiera hacerlo sin AJAX.

```
<form name="buscar" method="post" action="">

<tr>
  <td><input type="search" name="OT" id="OT"/></td>
  <td><input type="search" name="CUENTA"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar" /></td>
</tr>


<?php require("clase_buscar_tomas.php"); 
$OT = $_POST['OT'];
$CUENTA = $_POST['CUENTA'];


$reportes= new reporte();
$reg_reporte=$reportes->listartodos();
?>

<?php
//Se que estoy utilizando PHP obsoleto
$rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturacion_tomas WHERE OT ='$OT' 
OR CUENTA = '$CUENTA'", $conexion);
$num_registros = mysql_num_rows($rst_informe);
?>

<form method="POST" name="form">

<table align="center" id="tabla" border-color="white">

<tr>
  <th>OT</th>
  <th>FECHA</th>
  <th>CUENTA</th>
</tr>

<?php 
   while ($row_buscar=mysql_fetch_array($rst_informe)){
?>

<tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo 
  $row_buscar['id']; ?>" />

  <td><input type="number" name="OT" id="OT" value="<?php echo 
  $row_buscar['OT']; ?>" /></td>

  <td><input type="number" name="FECHA" id="FECHA" value="<?php echo 
  $row_buscar['FECHA']; ?>" /></td>

  <td><input type="number" name="CUENTA" id="CUENTA" value="<?php echo 
  $row_buscar['CUENTA']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<?php
  }
?>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: No se mucho de php, pero en cuanto a lógica no tendrías que preguntar: si OT y CUENTA llegan vacíos que haga un SELECT sin WHERE ?

Comment: si, pero no se como realizar la consulta de esa forma, si es embebida como la tendría que realizar...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no tiene que ser una sola consulta

```
if($OT == '' && $CUENTA =='') {
  $rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturacion_tomas", $conexion);
} else {
  $rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturacion_tomas WHERE OT ='$OT' 
    OR CUENTA = '$CUENTA'", $conexion);
}
```

Si de verdad necesitas hacerlo en una consulta podrías poner

```
$rst_informe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facturacion_tomas WHERE OT ='$OT' 
        OR CUENTA = '$CUENTA' OR ('$CUENTA' = '' AND '$OT' = '' )", $conexion);
```

Aunque la primera es mucha mejor opción ya que solo haces una comparación de los datos y no en la busqueda del sql.

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo haría algo así:

```
$string = "SELECT * FROM facturacion_tomas";

if($OT != '' && $CUENTA != ''){
    $string .= " WHERE OT=".$OT." OR CUENTA=". $CUENTA;
}

$rst_informe = mysql_query($string, $conexion);
$num_registros = mysql_num_rows($rst_informe);
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !